# Different results in manual and selenium execution

Tags: selenium

I have a strange scenario where I click on a button, it performs the button click and shows a filter result doing it manually. However the same is not showing the filtered result during my run in selenium (Note: I could click on that element using `xpath/linktext`). Appreciate your comments.

`Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@t='filter']")).Click();`

Comment: not a wait problem I guess, I have added sufficient waits before and after the click

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is happening after clicking the button in automation?

Comment: thank you Pradeep for your response. I have almost found the issue, as I 'm using the POM framework, I understand its the problem of the application if I go directly giving the URL it does not work actually. However it works fine if I use an icon to navigate to the position and click on the web element. So I found a valid issue in my application.